# For Binding Property in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, binding

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZdNB.jpg) This is the data that is stored in listview
I am trying to show ChampName and ChampImage on the page
Therefore, I used Binding in this code but nothing show up...

Please help me Thank you.

```
 public class UserChamp
    {
        
        [JsonProperty("championId")]
        public int champID { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("championPoints")]
        public int points { get; set; }
        public string ChampName { get; set; }
        public string ChampImage { get; set; }
       
        
    }
```

```
List<UserChamp> champList;

            for (int i = 0; i < userChamps.Length; i++)
            {
                if (userChamps[i].champID == Convert.ToInt32(championDTO.data.Aatrox.key))
                {
                    UserChamp user = new UserChamp {

                        ChampName = championDTO.data.Aatrox.name,
                        ChampImage = "http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/12.23.1/img/champion/Atrox.png"
                    
                    };
                    
                    champList.Add(user);
                }
                if (userChamps[i].champID == Convert.ToInt32(championDTO.data.Ahri.key))
                {
                    UserChamp user = new UserChamp
                    {

                        ChampName = championDTO.data.Ahri.name,
                        ChampImage = "http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/12.23.1/img/champion/Ahri.png"

                    };
                    champList.Add(user);
                } ....
 champLv.ItemsSource = champList;  // champLv is listview
```

// this is xml for showing champion Image and Names.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="FinalProject.Champions">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <ListView x:Name="champLv">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Image Source="{Binding ChampImage}" HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100" />
                                <Label Text="{Binding ChampName}" />
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

```
 private async void Clicked(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
        {
            champ = new Champions();
            await Navigation.PushAsync(champ, true);    

        }
```

I expect to see champion Images and Names.
The listview is saved correctly.
The page I want to show up is champ page so I am using await Navigation.PushAsync(champ, true); in my mainpage so I can go over to it when I click summoner icon

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve that shouldn’t matter, they are building the data first then assigning ItemsSource

Comment: @Jason I already checked it

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve  champLv.ItemsSource = champList;
            BindingContext = this; is this what you meant? This is not working if it is

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve he is not binding ItemsSource so that should have no impact.

Comment: hardcode a value in the `Label`s text property - that should help determine if `ItemsSource` is empty or if there is a problem with binding

Comment: @Jason I did Lable Text={Binding champID} and still not show up

Comment: That is not what I suggested.  I said **hardcode** a value - ie, `Text="blahblahblah"`

Comment: @Jason yeah this is weird when I hardcode it nothing shows up too

Comment: the page I want to show up is champ page so I am using await Navigation.PushAsync(champ, true); in my mainpage so I can go over to it when I click summoner icon

Comment: the question you asked has nothing to do with Navigation so I don't know why you think that is relevant

Comment: @Jason you mean the champList?

Comment: @Jason yes it has data

Comment: try using a `TextCell` instead of a `ViewCell` just to see if that will display the text value

Comment: @Jason yeah nothing show up...

Comment: I still think it’s a data problem.  If you’re willing to post your solution somewhere I can download it I’ll take a quick look.  Otherwise I’m out of ideas

Comment: @Jason can I email you? I can send it as zip file

Comment: If a hardcoded text string doesn't show up, and champList has elements, then something seems to prevent Xamarin from updating UI when you do `champLv.ItemsSource = champList`. Any relevant warnings in VS Output pane, when that page is shown? Did you set a breakpoint on that line, to confirm that it is executed? Where is that code called from? Page constructor?  `OnAppearing`?

Comment: The problem will turn out to be something about code that is not shown in the question. For example, the screenshot shows a call to a URI. Perhaps code execution is not on UI Thread (MainThread) when `champLv.ItemsSource = champList;` line is executed. Try `MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread( () => champLv.ItemsSource = champList );`

Comment: Have you worked it out?